# retrieve specific values from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a beginner in Android. I created a database with unique id, name, email etc. I want to retrieve the specific data from the database using the unique id. I don't know what to do. I read the previous answers but didn't get any idea from that.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should read **[SQL Database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)**

Below code is **DEMO**

```
 public String getSpecificResult(int getID) // you should pass getID from your Class
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String get_Status = "0";
    String selectQuery = "SELECT your_coloum_ FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + YOUR_UNIQUE_KEY + " = '"+ getID +"'";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

        get_Status = c.getString(0); // Return 1 selected result
    }
    db.close();
    return get_Status;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. 
 pass ur unique_id to get the contents.. alter names according to your table.

```
   public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```